# CMake: Compiler flags for each MSVC project type

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I am developing an C++ project that need to set specific compiler flags for each Visual Studio (MSVC) project configurations. We know that the configurations that CMake creates by default are these: **Debug**, **RelWithDebInfo**, **Release** and **MinSizeRel**.

In my CMakeLists.txt I am trying to do something like this:

```
# For each one Visual Studio configuration
# Some specifics compiler flags for MSVC

# For all RELEASE based configurations (Debug and RelWithDebInfo)
set(MSVC_FLAGS_REL STRING "/Ox /Ob2 /Oi /Ot /GF /Zc:wchar_t /MT")

# For all DEBUG based configurations (Release and MinSizeRel)
set(MSVC_FLAGS_DBG STRING "/MTd /Od /Zi /RTC1 /Zc:wchar_t /GS")
add_compile_options($<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${MSVC_FLAGS_DBG}>$<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:${MSVC_FLAGS_DBG}>$<$<CONFIG:Release>:${MSVC_FLAGS_REL}>$<$<CONFIG:MinSizeRel>:${MSVC_FLAGS_REL}>)
```

However, I try to build each one configurations I noticed that the compiler flags are not been successfully set. Also, I noticed a few posts that the Generator Expressions are sometimes inadvisable in some situations.

How should I properly set the compiler variables for Debug and Release based configurations?

Answer (score 1):

A bit dated, possibly, but I used this to good effect back in the days:

```
if ( MSVC )
    set_property( TARGET ... APPEND_STRING PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS <your set of flags> )
endif()
```

(My setup figured out the BUILD_TYPE and assembled the right set of flags based on that, instead of setting one set for Release and one for Debug just in case. This was pretty early in CMake's lifespan, so some of the more advanced plumbing just was not available yet.)